# Class 'App' not found while running cakephp shell

Tags: shell, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

Below is my shell class

**FriendShell.php**

```
require_once 'AppShell.php';

class FriendShell extends AppShell
{
      //code
}
```

**AppShell.php**

```
App::uses('Shell', 'Console');

class AppShell extends Shell {
    public function perform() {
        $this->initialize();
        $this->{array_shift($this->args)}();
    }
}
```

Reference to issue on

https://github.com/kamisama/Cake-Resque/issues/25

I removed

```
App::uses('AppShell', 'Console/Command');
```

and now using

```
require_once 'AppShell.php';
```

in FriendShell.php

But problem still remains because AppShell.php using

```
App::uses('Shell', 'Console');
```

That's why I am getting error **Class 'App' not found** when trying to run that shell.

Any help appreciated

Thank you

Comment: I don't think that's why you're getting that error. AppShell is a vendor package. Try this `App::uses('AppShell','Vendor/Shells');`. Also `App` would be undefined if you start the shell incorrectly.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Thanks for response,I tried you suggestion but still giving same error.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini,Let me clear scenario,currently I am in app directory 'php Console/Command/FriendShell.php' and executing this command.Is any problem with this?

Comment: No that's not how you execute a shell. Take a look at this. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#the-cakephp-console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with

```
Console/cake
```

It is CakeResque plugin and FriendShell.php is a job class therefore whole command is look like this now

```
Console/cake CakeResque.CakeResque enqueue default Friend "swapnil"
```

Comment: And it should also be noted, that `require_once 'AppShell.php';` is nonsense. What there was before was correct (the App::uses() statement).

Comment: @mark,Ok got it now but I did due to that same issue link.Thanks for your response